# How to upgrade angular version while keeping angular/cli one

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm struggling to install the right version of angular, I often get errors like `This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^11.0.0-next || >=11.0.0 <12.0.0, but Angular version 9.1.1 was found instead.`

I installed angular using `npm -g install @angular/cli@11.0.6` (as package.json of the project said was necessary), but when i do `ng --version` in the project, I have

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.1
Node: 14.15.5
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 9.1.1
```

I don't really understand what's going on, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can update angular CLI globally

1. uninstall CLI

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
```

2. install CLI to specific version

```
npm install @angular/cli@~9.1.0 -g
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I somehow still have the same error message in my project

Comment: if it not work you can update your angular project, https://angular.io/cli/update

Comment: I could, but since it's a group project, I would rather not force everyone to update to a newer version if i'm the only one facing the issue